# Should I carry out factor analysis based on this correlation matrix?

Tags: factor-analysis

I have a correlation matrix below and I am wondering if I should carry out a factor analysis. Are there issues of linear or multicollinearity?

MER RLTD    PCL PCP AL  ASW CSW ASL OPPO    WRY OPTM    ADPT

0.14
0.50    0.21
0.47    0.25    0.73
0.20    0.17    0.25    0.38
0.76    0.19    0.59    0.62    0.33
0.78    0.20    0.60    0.59    0.35    0.88
0.68    0.27    0.64    0.69    0.35    0.89    0.84
0.33    0.38    0.27    0.37    0.45    0.34    0.42    0.34
0.15    -0.09   0.26    0.22    0.09    0.14    0.08    0.17    -0.20
0.28    0.19    0.52    0.44    0.35    0.35    0.32    0.36    0.38    0.08
0.44    0.20    0.83    0.77    0.34    0.56    0.57    0.65    0.35    0.20    0.49

Comment: You could do exploratory factor analysis.

Comment: No multicollinearity is not an issue for EFA or PCA.

Comment: As Nike said, "Just do it."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course you can conduct a [factor analysis (FA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_analysis) with your correlation matrix. See the `R` code below where I fit an [exploratory FA (EFA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploratory_factor_analysis) model$^1$.

```
## Packages 
library(psych)
library(GPArotation)

## Data prep
# 1. Create lower triangle 
lower_tri_matrix <- diag(12)
lower_tri_matrix[2,1] <- c(0.14)
lower_tri_matrix[3,1:2] <- c(0.50,0.21)
lower_tri_matrix[4,1:3] <- c(0.47, 0.25, 0.73)
lower_tri_matrix[5,1:4] <- c(0.2, 0.17, 0.25, 0.38)
lower_tri_matrix[6,1:5] <- c(0.76, 0.19, 0.59, 0.62, 0.33)
lower_tri_matrix[7,1:6] <- c(0.78, 0.20, 0.60, 0.59, 0.35, 0.88)
lower_tri_matrix[8,1:7] <- c(0.68, 0.27, 0.64, 0.69, 0.35, 0.89, 0.84)
lower_tri_matrix[9,1:8] <- c(0.33, 0.38, 0.27, 0.37, 0.45, 0.34, 0.42, 0.34)
lower_tri_matrix[10,1:9] <- c(0.15, -0.09, 0.26, 0.22, 0.09, 0.14, 0.08, 0.17, -0.20)
lower_tri_matrix[11,1:10] <- c(0.28, 0.19, 0.52, 0.44, 0.35, 0.35, 0.32, 0.36, 0.38, 0.08)
lower_tri_matrix[12,1:11] <- c(0.44, 0.20, 0.83, 0.77, 0.34, 0.56, 0.57, 0.65, 0.35, 0.20, 0.49)

# 2. Identify the lower triangular part (including diagonal)
lower_part <- lower.tri(lower_tri_matrix, diag = TRUE)

# 3. Create an upper triangular part by transposing the lower part
upper_part <- t(lower_tri_matrix)

# 4. Combine the two parts
correlation_matrix <- lower_tri_matrix
correlation_matrix[!lower_part] <- upper_part[!lower_part]

## Fitting an EFA model
EFA_fit <- psych::fa(correlation_matrix, nfactors = 12,rotate = "varimax")
```

Regarding linearity, FA assumes a linear relationship between the observed variables and the underlying latent factors. This means that changes in the levels of the latent factors are expected to lead to proportional changes in the observed variables. I would not "worry" about linearity though, as approaches that don't assume linearity are quite advanced and seldom used in practice (e.g., though see Bauer, 2005 for a relatively accessible discussion of this topic). Multicollinearity on the other hand, like @utobi points out, is not an issue as in a FA context as high multicollinearity (or correlations) among variables suggest that these variables share a common underlying factor (which is a good thing)$^2$.

$^1$ See [this](https://quantdev.ssri.psu.edu/tutorials/intro-basic-exploratory-factor-analysis) link for an EFA tutorial using `R`.
$^2$ However, extremely high multicollinearity might indicate that several variables are essentially measuring the same thing.

**References**

Bauer, D. J. (2005). The role of nonlinear factor-to-indicator relationships in tests of measurement equivalence. Psychological Methods, 10(3), 305.